# remove permalink trailing slash

Tags: permalinks

I need to use the_permalink() in order to construct a simple link from each post . the link should be like

```
http://www.mysite.com/category/year/post-name?output=something..
```

I use ?output=something" >

the problem is that the trailing slash of the permalink is giving me an extar trailing slash that is breaking my link .

```
http://www.mysite.com/category/year/post-name/?output=something..
```

I know that I can construct the structure in another way , but I want to use the permalink (much easier) and i do not want to change the permalink structure sitewide ...

any way of getting rid of the trailing slash ??

Comment: None of these answers address the fact that a trailing slash is completely valid in this case and should not "break" the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `trim` command to do this, specifically, the `rtrim` to remove the character from the right side:

```
$url = rtrim(get_permalink(),'/');
```

Using a blanket `substr -1` technique would cause problems if there isn't a trailing slash in the permalink. Also, the function `the_permalink` echoes the link, and `get_permalink` returns it as a string.

Answer (score 2):

This post is old but, why not use WordPress build in function [untrailingslashit](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/untrailingslashit/)? Added since 2.2.0

```
function untrailingslashit( $string ) {
    return rtrim( $string, '/\\' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo substr(the_permalink(), 0, -1);
```

Comment: +1 to exit .. yep - I answered fast , but I believe that EXIT is right - better rtrim....

Answer (score 0):

We can add the following code in .httaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Don't forgot to select the custom link from backend and remove the trailing slash from postname.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/259124)