# get_permalink to an anchor

Tags: permalinks

Well, it's probably a dumb question but I don't know how to add an anchor to a permalink. I'm just trying to add a button in my posts list which leads directly to the comment section of the post. Something like this:

```
<li class="comment-btn">
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>#comments"><i class="icon-comment"></i></a>
</li>
```

The problem comes maybe by the slash just before the anchor?

my_site.com/my_post/#my_anchor

instead of

my_site.com/my_post#my_anchor

I'm still searching for an answer on Google but didn't find yet :/ Thanks...

**EDIT :** The problem doesn't comes from the slash. Thanks to czerspalace's answer, I removed the slash displayed before the anchor and the problem still remain.

Moreover, [westernjournalism.com](http://www.westernjournalism.com/) uses the same comment link and it works with the slash...

But for me, with or without a slash, when I click on the link I stay on the same page but it scroll to the bottom of the page. What a mistery...

Comment: Would something like this help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37994/remove-permalink-trailing-slash ?

Comment: Or get_comments_link() ?

Comment: Thanks czerspalace for your help. I'll try get_comments_link() (thanks Andy) but will it works even if there is no comment yet on the post? I'll check that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Andy, this is working:

```
<li class="comment-btn">
    <a href="<?php echo get_comments_link( $post->ID ); ?>">
        <i class="icon-comment"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```